# How do I get tableView.reloadData() to work properly with core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview

When I run the app, I am able to populate the cells in my `tableview` but when I save (from a separate view controller) and go back to the `tableview controller`, **tableView.reloadData()** gets called but nothing happens. I use the notification center to reload the data before popping back.

**TableViewController.swift:**

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Pet> = {
    let fetchRequest = PersistenceManager.shared.fetchRequest()
    let context = PersistenceManager.shared.context
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc as! NSFetchedResultsController<Pet>
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(pushToAddPetViewController))
    tableView.register(MainTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
}

@objc func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**AddPetVC.swift:**

```
func saveContext() {
    // Inputs saved to coreData
    PersistenceManager.shared.saveContext()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fetched data in viewDidLoad() which will not be called when you come back to the view. You should fetch  data in viewWillAppear() and reload from that or from the notification observer method loadList(notification: NSNotification) . So, add the below code in viewWillAppear() or loadList(notification: NSNotification) :

```
 do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you popViewController to call back to previous ViewController, viewWillAppear() will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

Create fetchedResultsController instance and conform to NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate. NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate will observe the changes and reflect changes on UI

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Pet> = {
           let fetchRequest = PersistenceManager.shared.fetchRequest()
           let context = PersistenceManager.shared.context
           let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
           frc.delegate = self

           return frc as! NSFetchedResultsController<Pet>
    }()
```

In your viewDidLoad

```
do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print("Unable to Save Note")
            print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

Now implement NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

```
extension YourController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        uiTableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        uiTableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch (type) {
        case .insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                uiTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;
        case .delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                uiTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;
        case .update:
            if let indexPath = indexPath, let cell = uiTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? UserCell {
                configureCell(cell, at: indexPath)
            }
            break;
        case .move:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                uiTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }

            if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                uiTableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Implement UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate

```
extension YourController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {
            return 0
        }

        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PetCell", for: indexPath) as! Pet
        configureCell(cell, at: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let pet = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
            //let user = viewModel.user(for: indexPath.row)
            let pet = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
            //Delete pet and reload table
        }
    }

    func configureCell(_ cell: Pet, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let pet = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
}
```

For more details and code follow the demo project
https://github.com/rheyansh/CoreDataDemo